# Getting flash messages to display under navbar in semantic UI

Tags: css, node.js, express, semantic-ui, flash-message

Using Node.js with express. I'm trying to get flash messages to pop up underneath my navbar, but they currently are popping up behind it so that they are not visible. If I inspect and add margin to the top of it, they come underneath, but it pushes the rest of the page way farther down than anyone would like. Here's my code:

```
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui fixed inverted menu">
    <div class="ui container">
      <div class="header item">
        <i class="music icon"></i><a href="/">Music Notes</a>
      </div>
      <% if(!currentUser){ %>
      <a href="/login" class="item">Log In</a>
      <a href="/signup" class="item">Sign Up</a>
      <a href="/about" class="item">About</a>
      <% } else{ %>
      <a href="/users/<%= currentUser._id %>" class="item">Hello, <%= currentUser.username %>!</a>
      <a href="/logout" class="item">Logout</a>
      <% } %>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <% if(error && error.length > 0){ %>
    <div class="ui bottom attached error message"></div>
          <%= error %>
    </div>
  <% } %> 
  <% if(success && success.length > 0){ %>
    <div class="ui bottom attaced success message" role="alert"></div>
        <%= success %>
    </div>
  <% } %>
  
</div>
```

And a screen grab of the issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGkuM.png

Thanks to anyone that can help!

Comment: Can you expose your localhost with ngrok orsimilar?

Comment: It appears not. I'm using WSL2 and I don't think the two are cooperating very well.

Comment: If you can create a sandbox, I can help you with it: https://codesandbox.io/s/

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-yalow-dxgrc problem file is views/partials/header.ejs

Comment: There is no success message triggered in that Sandbox after I click on the buttons.